# Need help in avoiding the view which is used in (inner) join multiple times in a query

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

We have a query that uses multiple inner joins
Now here, we are doing inner join on the same view multiple times.
its like hierarchy type join

This results in increased execution time for the query.

**Query**

```
    Select field1, field2 ... few fields
    FROM 
    CUST_MART.v_CPM AS P 
    JOIN CUST_MART.V_CPM_MART_HIER AS C ON p.prod_cl = c.prod_cl 
    AND g.lvl = c.lvl 
    JOIN CUST_MART.V_CPM_MART_CLASS AS D0 ON c.prod_cl_0 = d0.prod_cl 
    AND c.lvl_0 = d0.lvl 
    JOIN CUST_MART.V_CPM_MART_CLASS AS D2 ON c.prod_cl_2 = d2.prod_cl 
    AND c.lvl_2 = d2.lvl 
    JOIN CUST_MART.V_CPM_MART_CLASS AS D3 ON c.prod_cl_3 = d3.prod_cl 
    AND c.lvl_3 = d3.lvl 
    JOIN CUST_MART.V_CPM_MART_CLASS AS D6 ON c.prod_cl_6 = d6.prod_cl 
    AND c.lvl_6 = d6.lvl 
    JOIN CUST_MART.v_CPM_upc AS V on p.skt = v.skt
```

Will this query work -

```
    Select field1, field2 ... few fields
    FROM 
    CUST_MART.v_CPM AS P 
    JOIN CUST_MART.V_CPM_MART_HIER AS C ON p.prod_cl = c.prod_cl 
    AND g.lvl = c.lvl 
    JOIN CUST_MART.V_CPM_MART_CLASS AS D0 ON c.prod_cl_0 = d0.prod_cl 
    AND c.lvl_0 = d0.lvl 
    AND c.prod_cl_2 = d0.prod_cl 
    AND c.lvl_2 = d0.lvl 
    AND c.prod_cl_3 = d0.prod_cl 
    AND c.lvl_3 = d0.lvl 
    AND c.prod_cl_6 = d0.prod_cl 
    AND c.lvl_6 = d0.lvl 
    JOIN CUST_MART.v_CPM_upc AS V on p.skt = v.skt
```

**Request**

- Will my rewritten query work?
- i cant run on prod, so cant test this with the existing data
- This query takes 4 hours and runs daily and so the need to fix this query
- is there any other approach i can consider

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before you start!

Comment: You can not escape a join, somehow you need to apply the join if you need it. One option would be executing this result and saving it as a different table and using it.

Comment: If you can redesign the underlying tables then try to build the tree(hierarchy structure) in one table which will eliminate the need for multiple joins. Or you can use UNION operation to stack them all and use it in one go

Comment: hello @AjanBalakumaran , Is execution time expected to  drop if i save it as different table and use it here, in entire query context ?

Comment: Hello @SriniV, thanks for the suggestion, do u know any example or pointer i can refer to for hierarchy structure. this query runs daily so i will consider that option. in case of union, i may still need joins( or not ?)

Comment: You need to post your actual SQL to make out anything at all. Dont drastically change the scope of a question. Instead ask a new question. You edit is too much as it changed scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your rewritten query will not work.  Consider this `JOIN`:

```
JOIN CUST_MART.V_CPM_MART_CLASS D0
ON c.prod_cl_0 = d0.prod_cl AND
   c.lvl_0 = d0.lvl AND
   c.prod_cl_2 = d0.prod_cl AND
   c.lvl_2 = d0.lvl AND
   c.prod_cl_3 = d0.prod_cl AND
   c.lvl_3 = d0.lvl AND
   c.prod_cl_6 = d0.prod_cl AND
   c.lvl_6 = d0.lvl
```

This only matches when:

```
c.lvl_0 = c.lvl_1 = c.lvl_2 = c.lvl_3 = c.lvl_6
```

This condition is not in your original query.  My guess is that this is never true in your data.

Comment: many, many thanks, this helps and clarifies my understanding too